# In localhost it runs fine, but when trying to be deployed to aws (eb deploy) gives out the following error:

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-0a71c104c0eea1e7c] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...on/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named import_export.
```

Comment: What are you trying to deploy ?

Comment: deploy the application with django frameworks and python 2.7 using elasticbeanstalk

Comment: `import_export` file should be in your configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it turns out I need to add django-import-export to my requirements.txt